# Monitoring changes in Google Drive files for whole domain using Drive API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, scalability, google-apps

we are creating Google Drive moderation application to keep list of changes for all files in a Gapps domain. The problem is that we need to impersonificate as every single user - one by one - in order to get all the changes since it seems there is no global API method for this.

This is terrible approach for scalability since we have loads of users (10000+) and loads of changes for each of them.

Is there any way to get changes of files for whole domain at one shot or at least in some more scalable way? Google Drive API docs are no help here. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use  domain-wide delegation of authority to get all the changes : https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

Comment: @voscausa: We already do have service account working. But this doesn't help you with neccessity of querying data for each single user separately which is the main problem.

Comment: Maybe you can create a drive apps script to monitor user drive modifications and push them to your app engine application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation) simplifies the authentication portion for your app but you'll still need to auth as each user to get their files and changes.

It may be possible for your app to "grab" all files and make itself (or a special user) the owner, then you just have one user account to scan but the "grab" process would still need to run at regular intervals to find new files created or uploaded by end users.

I believe most apps that need to scan content at this level do it via cron jobs or AppEngine [task queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) which make it easy to chunk up the scans throughout the day. Generally they expect to scan each user account once every 24 hours or so.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to make our app the owner of the files. We actually tried to do it using task queues, but now it seems that the backend instances are a better way because of threading support. This way, we can spawn tens of threads querying up user specific data. But still, this seems like very rough way to overcome the impossibility of gathering all changes at once :(

Comment: Do you need owner access or would granting your special user account edit/view access to each file work as a way to centralize the access?

Comment: We probably need owner access since a lot of file metainformation (like file ACL) would be inaccessible otherwise.