# Google Drive API - How to work with the domain-wide service account

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I was trying to use the service account of my app to access to all documents of all users in my domain following this instruction:

https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation
But it didn't work.
Could you please help me out on this??
I tried to follow URL -

http://iambusychangingtheworld.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/google-drive-api-how-work-with-domain.html

and code -

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL")
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                        new java.io.File("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH"))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
                .setServiceAccountUser("abc@xyz.com").build();
```

its working fine But should give me details for all the user for this domain... instead it gives me only for one useraccount.. In the Service account doc it says it should be able to access all the users data under this domain.. am I missing something>?
FYI... Scopes are added , APIS are enabled for this account

Is there any way I can get it??
I have also seen below links but was not of  -
[Not able to access my google drive Files with service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427998/not-able-to-access-my-google-drive-files-with-service-account)

Comment: This is of same type listed here but still not working -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021007/monitoring-changes-in-google-drive-files-for-whole-domain-using-drive-api/25114664?noredirect=1#comment39086108_25114664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service account with domain-wide delegation allows you to access each account's data **one at a time**.

If you want to access all the users' data in a domain, you will need to generate a different token for each user (passing the email in the `setServiceAccountUser()` method) and make the API call for each user.

Comment: Hi David , Thanks a lot for your quick help on this.1.  So this means I need to have all the users email address under this domain and set them(in setServiceAccountUser) one by one for all the records ..?  . 2. is there anyway other way.. by which without providing all the email ID(in case there are 1k-10k records)one by one?

Comment: Yes you need to know all the email adresses. You can find them using the Directory API. I cannot find any other option, and I had to do it for 28k users and 1M docs :-) Note that you will not be able to access the Drive API if the user is suspended.

Comment: Thanks Mate, Really appreciate it... Going mad on this from long as im again n again going back to the settings thinking am I missing anything... This URL I found which shows that we could get it - http://iambusychangingtheworld.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/google-drive-api-how-work-with-domain.html    so I was working around it for a while.. but still did not get it... but why so, since we are using the service account we should be able to get the list of user data at one shot by giving the Service Account admin user(using which we created the account)... may be iam wrong here

Comment: I had the exact same requirements as you, the only way is to use setAccountUser for each user. I also tried using an admin user but it does not work.

Comment: Hi David, Just one more thing.. If I take any user from the list and set it in setServiceAccountUser(test1@xyz.com) . it gives me the error   - Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "error" : "access_denied",
  "error_description" : "Requested client not authorized."
}  .. So how do we pass the token with the request here..

Comment: No idea. I think you should open another SO question so that other people can help on it.